# Get zip file from RestRequest

Tags: c#, rest, zip, restsharp

For REST calls I use RestSharp, I have to call a service that has to return me a zip file which I will then save on File System

```
public bool DownloadZip(int id)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                
                var request = new RestRequest("download/zip", DataFormat.Json);
                request.AddHeader("authorization", _token);
                request.AddHeader("ID", _id.ToString());
                request.AddQueryParameter("id", id.ToString());

                var response =  new RestClient(url).Get(request);
                response.ContentType = "application/zip";

                _logFile.Debug($"downloaded result {id}: {response.IsSuccessful} {response.StatusCode}");

                if (response.IsSuccessful && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.Content))
                {
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.Content)))
                    {
                        using (var zip = File.OpenWrite(path: @"C:\temp\temp.zip"))
                        {
                            zip.CopyTo(stream);
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    _logFile.Warn($"Download Unauthorized {id}: {response.IsSuccessful} {response.StatusCode} {response.Content}");
                    _authToken = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    _logFile.Error($"Download {id}: {response.IsSuccessful} {response.StatusCode} {response.Content}");
                    throw new Exception("DownloadZip Failed");
                }
            }
        }
```

The line of code "`zip.CopyTo(stream);`" returns "The stream does not support reading" as an error.
Is there any setting to set to ensure that it does not return an error?
Testing the call on Postman I noticed that in the response header I have Content-Disposition from this can I go back to the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RestSharp 107 you can use

```
var stream = await client.DownloadStreamAsync(request);
```

It will give you a stream and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution by myself, thanks anyway yours is correct